# registry file creation in visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, authentication, registry

I want to check my login data (username and password) for three times if the input is invalid after the three trials the program should to be stopped for one hour by creating reg file that reads the time from last attempt of failed login to one hour later , so the problem is how can I create that reg file and stop the program for one hour ... regards

Comment: Of course you realize that this method is really easy to bypass, right?

Comment: This question is too broad to be asked here and doesn't address a specific programming issue. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I tend to store this type of information where I've stored the user credentials rather than in the registry. Typically, this is a database and never the registry. Registry keys can be modified by any privileged user.

Usually, when the user has exceeded the failure threshold, you want to simply make the login workflow slower to respond to future requests. This will slow down brute force attacks.

If this is a shared application, then you only want to affect the users that have exceeded their login failures. Otherwise, it makes it too easy for someone to create a denial of service attack by simply causing login failures.